# PHP: What SPL exception should I do if a variable value is wrong?

Tags: php, exception, spl

There are two similar exception in php: the [RangeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.rangeexception.php) and the [UnexpectedValueException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php). Both are subclasses of the [RuntimeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php). The problem is, I don't see much difference.

**[RangeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.rangeexception.php)**
Exception thrown to indicate range errors during program execution. Normally this means there was an arithmetic error other than under/overflow. This is the runtime version of [DomainException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php).

**[UnexpectedValueException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)**
Exception thrown if a value does not match with a set of values. Typically this happens when a function calls another function and expects the return value to be of a certain type or value not including arithmetic or buffer related errors.

I know it is a runtime error. If a variable type is wrong, it is simple, I should use the [UnexpectedValueException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php).

What should I do if a variable **value** is wrong?

Comment: It depends in what way it's wrong.... if a variable must be within a set range (e.g. 1-10) and you get `20` or `-10` or `0`, then you throw a `RangeException`; if you get `ABC` or `NULL` then you throw an `UnexpectedValueException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks it is the best to stay with the `UnexpectedValueException`.

1. I haven’t found any convention.
2. The *unexpected value* is a better descriptions for programmers.
3. If there is a special recovery code, a custom exception would be better.